# How to rewrite the formula?

Tags: angular

I have this function:

```
  getApplyAll (arr ){
    return   100 * arr.reduce((sum, n) => sum + +n.apply, 0) / arr.reduce((sum, n) => sum + +n.count, 0);
  };
```

The function itself works correctly. The problem is that it displays the result in this form: `35.294117647058826`. How can  reduce the result to such a `35.29`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `toFixed(2)` function.

```
getApplyAll (arr ){
    let result = 100 * arr.reduce((sum, n) => sum + +n.apply, 0) / arr.reduce((sum, n) => sum + +n.count, 0);
    return result.toFixed(2)
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getApplyAll (arr ){
    let result = 100 * arr.reduce((sum, n) => sum + +n.apply, 0) / 
    arr.reduce((sum, n) => sum + +n.count, 0);
    return Math.round(100 * result)/100
```

};

If you are using `toFixed` don't forget that the result will be a *string* (not a *number*) so you may have to convert

```
result = parseInt(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `toFixed(2)` for this..

```
getApplyAll(arr){
    return 100 * arr.reduce((sum, n) => sum + +n.apply, 0) / arr.reduce((sum, n) => sum + +n.count, 0).toFixed(2);
};
```